# How can I change mouse cursor size?

Tags: 11.10, mouse, cursor

I'm using 11.10 and I'd like to change mouse cursor size more bigger.

How can I do it?

I cannot find any settings of mouse cursor size.

Comment: For Ubuntu 12.04/14.04/16.04 and newer releases this question has more up-to-date answers: [How do I change the cursor and its size?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126491/how-do-i-change-the-cursor-and-its-size)

Answer (score 2):

**Question**

Your desktop enviroment ?

(http://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-different-des-shells-are-available)

**It seems**

It seems that, if your cursor theme supports multiple sizes then you could change the mouse cursor size /1/,/2/,/3/. Either with the .Xresources /4/ file or with your DE configuration file. The KDE is using kcminputrc /3/, the gui is on the way.

The easiest way to enlarge the mouse size is to install and enable a mouse theme with larger pointers.

**Background**

The X11 mouse themes are composed from the pixel images /5/. So they have a native resolution, scaling could make them pixelated.

**Links**

1. http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=65730
2. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X11_Cursors
3. https://git.reviewboard.kde.org/r/101701/
4. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_resources
5. http://www.ehow.com/how_5026012_make-cursors-file-ubuntu.html